# Compiling with -march causes threads to say "pure virtual method called"

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, gcc, raspberry-pi

I am trying to compile my C++ Raspberry Pi 3 code through gcc with a `-march=armv8-a` flag. However, using this flag causes my threads to fail by saying `pure virtual method called`. I know it is the `-march=armv8-a` flag because when I compile it without it, the threads start working again.

Please note: The thread does not even start, it just gives a `pure virtual method called`

Can someone compile this with `-march=armv8-a` on their Raspberry Pi 3 and report back on what they got?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

void threadedFunction()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from thread" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(threadedFunction);
    sleep(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you both `detach()`ing and `join()`ing a thread?

Comment: @justin I dumbed down my original code.

Comment: @KevinDuarte It is still wrong. You should be getting an exception from doing that, because once you've `detach`ed, you can't `join` anymore.

Comment: @KevinDuarte [Cppreference for `std::detach`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach): "After calling detach *this no longer owns any thread." If the problem goes away when you remove the `detach()`, my guess is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Justin & InternetAussie I updated the question with my original code now

Comment: @KevinDuarte In either case, the same problem with `detach()` and `join()` is there.

Comment: @KevinDuarte You are still `detach`ing and then `join`ing. Try removing the `detach` call and see what happens.

Comment: An [mcve] is code that reproduces your problem, not code vaguely like your code.  Does this have the same symptoms?  Then the detach/join seems like an issue.

Comment: @InternetAussie I removed `detach` and it still says `pure virtual method called`

Comment: Debug, debug, debug.

Comment: @InternetAussie I tried everything, it seems as if Gcc has a thread bug when compiling for ARM processors with `-march` flags.

Comment: It's far more likely that the your code has a bug, than gcc, a compiler used all over the world to compile thousands of multithreaded programs, and with an extensive internal testsuite. Just because a particular compiler option results in your code crashing doesn't necessarily mean that it's a problem with a compiler option. It shouldn't be too hard, for example, to write some code that crashes with `-O2`. The problem would not be this compiler option, but buggy code. Look for bugs in your code, rather than a problem with your compiler.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Even with simplified code (updated code) it still does not work. `-march=armv8-a` causes `pure virtual method called`. Removing `-march=armv8-a` allows the threads to work again

Comment: I find it highly unlikely that gcc would have a generic bug of this kind that's exhibited by such trivial code. It's far more plausible that there's some kind of a configuration or an installation problem with your gcc that you're using. Maybe some of the runtime libraries are not installed, or the wrong libraries are getting linked. Unfortunately, there's only one user on stackoverflow.com that knows the intimate details of your gcc installation, and how it's configured. That user would be you, of course.

Comment: ARMv8-a is a 64-bit platform. Are you actually using a 64-bit kernel? (RPi3 only shipped with 32-bit kernels originally, not sure about now)

Comment: @M.M Yup, completely forgot about Raspian-Lite having a 32 bit kernel despite the RPi3 having a 64 bit processor.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it seems plausible to me that nobody tried using the particular combination of compiler, flags, hardware platform, OS, and ISO C++ threading,  as OP is on.  Also there have been plenty of gcc bugs exhibited by trivial code in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `armv8-a` uses a 64-bit architecture, using the `-march=armv8-a` flag is going to compile for a 64-bit machine. However, many Raspberry Pi OS(images) are 32-bit which may cause crashes or errors.

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m